# Alternative to Youtube Data API v2.0 Standard video feeds in v3.0 after April 20, 2015?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

In Youtube Data API v2.0 there is a way to retrieve most_popular videos in standard video feeds by

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular

But after April 20, 2015 after deprecation this kind of feed wont be available.

Is there any work around for this in Youtube Data API v3.0?

Answer (score 0):

There is a #PopularOnYouTube channel. You could grab the videos from that channel with v3.